# Where are these error and warning icons as a java resource?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I've got a custom tree cell renderer that I'm using to render custom icons a JTree, and I really like the warning icon and the error icon that JOptionPane displays for both warning messages and error messages respectively. Obviously I can use the following code to get the icons for my own use, but this is way heavy handed and requires me to instantiate dialogs that I'm never going to use:

```
public class ValidationCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    private Icon warnIcon;
    private Icon errorIcon;

    public ValidationCellRenderer() {
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(new Object(), 
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        warnIcon = optionPane.getIcon();
        optionPane = new JOptionPane(new Object(), 
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        errorIcon = optionPane.getIcon();
    }
}
```

There's got to be a better way to get these icons as a resource, but I'm not finding an easy way to do this from the Java API. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We use them too via:

```
UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon")

UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon")
```

Answer (score 8):

And if you want to know about all the icons and their names you can check out: [UIManager Defaults](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=uimanager-defaults)