# Information icon

Tags: java, swing

I would like to make use in a normal JDialog of the information icon provided by the JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE. Is it possible?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196797/where-are-these-icons-as-a-java-resource

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently in the JOptionPane source code (rather in its UI, actually), this is done by retrieving this property:

```
return (Icon)DefaultLookup.get(optionPane, this, "OptionPane.informationIcon");
```

Outside of a UI code, though, you simply need to call:

```
UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon")
```

Note however that the icon returned depends on the current Look & Feel.

---

Out of curiosity, the other resources are:

- "OptionPane.errorIcon"
- "OptionPane.warningIcon"
- "OptionPane.questionIcon"