# JComboBox on Windows 7 has rendering artifacts

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

When I use a JComboBox on Windows 7, the four corners each have a pixel that doesn't match the background colour of the parent component.

In Windows 8 this problem doesn't happen (although that could be because in Windows 8, the JComboBox is rendered as a perfect rectangle). Nor does it happen on OS X.

What can I do to make the corner pixels let the background colour of the parent component through?

Here's an image showing the problem:

[image]

Here's a self-contained code example I'm using:

```
import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WindowsLookAndFeel());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"One", "Two"});
                contentPane.add(comboBox);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this issue... but i thought it would be normal. maybe you have to set all backgroundcolors of the components (the combobox included) to the same color.

Comment: What `UIManager` [defaults](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197350/230513) in `WindowsLookAndFeel` have you tried?

Comment: @trashgod sadly this is default in Win7, only to override Borders, common issue from Win Vista + Aero

Comment: @trashgod I haven't changed any defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the border...

```
comboBox.setBorder(null);
```

[image]

The next choice would be to design a specialised look and feel delegate that achieved what you wanted on Windows...

For example...

```
public static class MyComboBoxUI extends WindowsComboBoxUI {

    @Override
    protected void installDefaults() {
        super.installDefaults();
        LookAndFeel.uninstallBorder(comboBox);
    }

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return new MyComboBoxUI();
    }

}
```

And then install it using...

```
UIManager.put("ComboBoxUI", MyComboBoxUI.class.getName());
```

This will mean you won't need to remove the borders from every combo box you create

Or, you could simply override the default border property in the `UIManager`...

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.border", new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Either way, it will effect all combo boxes created after you apply it...

Comment: Changing the UI property ComboBox.border worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

First thing I would try is setOpaque(false) on the JComboBox.

Also you should not set the WindowLookAndFeel directly. Instead set the *System default* L&F:

```
// force platform native look & feel
try {
    final String className = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(className);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    // ignore
}
```

That will always set the OS's default look and feel, regardless of what OS you're running on.