# Java JScrollBar vs BasicScrollBarUI issue

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollbar

Because of some glitchy jscrollbar issues (see note below) I had to create a custom UI for a vertical scrollbar in a specific scenario. In doing so the default look/ colors changed. Does anyone know the settings/ overrides to make BasicScrollBarUI look like the default jscrollbar?

for some context this is what my code is doing:

```
          JScrollBar verticalJScrollBar= new JScrollBar();
          verticalJScrollBar.setUI(new CustomUI());
          ////
          class CustomUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {
          }
```

*Note- I am using Java 1.4.2 so that impacted the solutions I took as well as my options going forward.

Comment: You'd need to go through each and every look and feel you want to support and extend from each of those UI delegates...

Comment: Use the utility cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197350/230513)